# How to retrieve raw buffer from android surfaceview object

Tags: android

I have `SurfaceView`, `SurfaceHolder` and `Surface` objects. I learned that `Surface` holds raw buffer. And I want to use this buffer and convert it to `jpeg` images. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25091703/how-to-create-and-save-a-screenshot-from-a-surfaceview