# Take realtime screenshot while video calling android

Tags: android, video, screenshot

I have problem with my android code for taking screenshot while on video calling

I found several method for take screenshot on specific layout and this is what I used :

```
private void takeScreenshot() {
    final FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.remote_video_view_container);
    Date now = new Date();
    android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

    try {
        // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
        String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";

        // create bitmap screen capture
        container.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(container.getDrawingCache());
        container.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        File imageFile = new File(mPath);

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);

        if(mPath!=null){
            Toast savedToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Drawing saved to Gallery!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            savedToast.show();
        }
        else{
            Toast unsavedToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Oops! Image could not be saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            unsavedToast.show();
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        openScreenshot(imageFile);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        // Several error may come out with file handling or DOM
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void openScreenshot(File imageFile) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

i try this code for save my draw painting application that will save the drawing layout and then i try to use the same method for save video call layout but return black screen image.
i found that this method cannot use for real-time when i want to record it in video

source : [How to programmatically take a screenshot in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-in-android)

so, anyone help me what the best way to solve my problem ?

Comment: I had the same issue in my photoeditting app. Content on Surfaceview was not getting captured. Please check this link for solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25091703/how-to-create-and-save-a-screenshot-from-a-surfaceview

Please vote if it works! ;-)

Comment: thanks for ur advice. i'll try it :)

Comment: i already tried ur suggestion but still didnt work Singh